# Troubles reading AMD ISA code

Tags: assembly, opencl, gpu, disassembly

I'm having trouble reading the assembly language of AMD Southern Island GPUs using the documentation found [here](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/AMD_Southern_Islands_Instruction_Set_Architecture.pdf).

Here is a sample OpenCL code:

```
 1    __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(256, 1, 1)))
 2    void kernel foo(global uchar* data) {
 3        const uint block_size = get_local_size(0);
 4        const uint lid = get_local_id(0);
 5        
 6        data[lid] = max(data[lid], data[lid + block_size]);
 7    }
```

And the (dis)assembly produced by the AMD compiler:

```
 1    shader main
 2      asic(SI_ASIC)
 3      type(CS)
 4    
 5      s_buffer_load_dword  s0, s[8:11], 0x00                 // what is the purpose of s[8:11] ?
 6      s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)
 7      v_add_i32     v1, vcc, s0, v0                          // I guess v0 initially contains the local IDs ?
 8      v_add_i32     v0, vcc, s0, v0                          // wouldn't a v_mov v0, v1 performs better ?
 9      buffer_load_ubyte  v2, v1, s[4:7], 0 offen             // s[4:7] ?
10      buffer_load_ubyte  v0, v0, s[4:7], 0 offen offset:256
11      s_waitcnt     vmcnt(0)
12      v_max_u32     v0, v2, v0
13      buffer_store_byte  v0, v1, s[4:7], 0 offen glc
14      s_endpgm
15    end
```

- What I don't understand is how I could have ended up writing, for instance, a *buffer_load_ubyte* instruction with only the ISA manual (see section 12.6 *Vector Memory Buffer Instructions*) ?
- How am I supposed to read the microcode informations ? (for exemple: p. 161 for the *v_add_i32* instruction)
- Is there any standard way to discribe a processor architecture ?

Thanks !

**Ps : some bonus questions are in the assembly code comments**

Comment: My guess regarding `s[8:11]` would be that it denotes a subset of the SGPRs, in this case `s8, s9, s10, s11`. And similarly for `s[4:7]`.

Comment: Yes, I came to this conclusion too, but what are they used for in theses instructions ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm about a year late but maybe this will help someone else.

understanding the AMD GCN all comes down to this:

```
Address = BASE + offset + lane
```

On kernel launch the following registers are pre-loaded

- s[4:7] is the base address
- s[8:11] is a pointer to the parameter
- offsets v0 is pre-loaded with the lane number (0-63)

In a nutshell, we are going to (1) get the address *data (2) Get the value at *data (3) get the value at offset:256 (4) add the two numbers (5) Store the results bad to *data.

```
shader main
  asic(SI_ASIC)
  type(CS)

  s_buffer_load_dword  s0, s[8:11], 0x00  // s[8:11] is the pointer to the params
  s_waitcnt     lgkmcnt(0)           // wait for s0 to be filled
  v_add_i32     v1, vcc, s0, v0      // s0=offset v0=lane We just need the base now.
  v_add_i32     v0, vcc, s0, v0      // wouldn't a v_mov v0, v1 performs better
  buffer_load_ubyte v2, v1, s[4:7], 0 offen //Get value at Base(s[4:7]) + v1(offset & lane) 
  buffer_load_ubyte v0, v0, s[4:7], 0 offen offset:256 // like above but address+256
  s_waitcnt     vmcnt(0)                        //wait for the memory transfer to complete
  v_max_u32     v0, v2, v0                      // do the MAX operation
  buffer_store_byte v0, v1, s[4:7], 0 offen glc //save v0 using the base+v1(offset+lane)
  s_endpgm                                      //stop kernel
end
```

using a "v_mov v0, v1" instead of a "v_add_i32 v0, vcc, s0, v0" on line 10 would not make it go faster because the v_mov and v_add both take the same amount of time. If this were on a CPU however, the v_mov would be slower because it depends on the prevous instruciton and it cannot do multiple instrucitons at once. A gpu cannot do multiple instructions at once on a core so both ways would be the same speed.

*What I don't understand is how I could have ended up writing, for instance, a buffer_load_ubyte instruction with only the ISA manual (see section 12.6 Vector Memory Buffer Instructions)?* It is kind of hard to follow. You almost need to learn by example.

*How am I supposed to read the microcode information?* (for exemple: p. 161 for the *v_add_i32* instruction) It is hard to do this. You almost need to do some trail and error. The manual is incorrect actually in a few spots and I reported it to AMD in the forums. I built a compiler (asm4gcn) and I had to struggle on this. I also used other peoples projects for reference.

*Is there any standard way to describe a processor architecture?* I guess they are all different in some ways.  But most have a cache section, floating point units, control flow units, and registers.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this here for the world. This is some SI assembly I was given as part of a class I'm taking. Helps understand a bit of what's going on with the ABI, granted this code is run on top of Multi2sim.

```
.global vector_add
.args
    i32* src1 0 uav10 RO
    i32* src2 16 uav11 RO
    i32* dst 32 uav12 RW
.metadata
    uavprivate = 0
    hwregion = 0
    hwlocal = 0
    FloatMode = 192
    IeeeMode = 0
    # Loads UAV table in s2...s3
    userElements[0] = PTR_UAV_TABLE, 0, s[2:3]
    # Loads constant buffer 0 descriptor in s4...s7
    userElements[1] = IMM_CONST_BUFFER, 0, s[4:7]
    # Loads constant buffer 1 descriptor in s8...s11
    userElements[2] = IMM_CONST_BUFFER, 1, s[8:11]
    # Forces wg_id[0] (work-group ID in dimension 0) to be available in s12
    COMPUTE_PGM_RSRC2:USER_SGPR = 12
    COMPUTE_PGM_RSRC2:TGID_X_EN = 1
.text
    # Load lsize[0] into s0
    s_buffer_load_dword s0, s[4:7], 0x04
    # Load src1, src2, and dst base addresses (arguments) from CB1
    s_buffer_load_dword s4, s[8:11], 0x00
    s_buffer_load_dword s5, s[8:11], 0x04
    s_buffer_load_dword s6, s[8:11], 0x08
    # Load UAVs from UAV table
    s_load_dwordx4 s[20:23], s[2:3], 0x50
    s_load_dwordx4 s[24:27], s[2:3], 0x58
    s_load_dwordx4 s[28:31], s[2:3], 0x60
    # Waits for memory operations to complete
    s_waitcnt lgkmcnt(0)
    # v1 <= lsize[0]
    v_mov_b32 v1, s0
    # v1 <= lsize[0] * wg_id[0]
    v_mul_i32_i24 v1, s12, v1
    # v2 <= lsize[0] * wg_id[0] + lid[0] = gid[0]
    v_add_i32 v2, vcc, v0, v1
    # v3 <= gid[0] * 4
    v_lshlrev_b32 v3, 2, v2
    # Calcaulte effective addresses
    v_add_i32 v10, vcc, s4, v3
    v_add_i32 v11, vcc, s5, v3
    v_add_i32 v12, vcc, s6, v3
    # Load src1[id] and src2[id]
    tbuffer_load_format_x v20, v10, s[20:23], 0 offen format:[BUF_DATA_FORMAT_32, BUF_NUM_FORMAT_FLOAT]
    tbuffer_load_format_x v21, v11, s[24:27], 0 offen format:[BUF_DATA_FORMAT_32,BUF_NUM_FORMAT_FLOAT]
    # Waits for memory operations to complete
    s_waitcnt vmcnt(0)
    # Add source elements
    v_add_i32 v22, vcc, v20, v21
    # Store result in dst[id]
    tbuffer_store_format_x v22, v12, s[28:31], 0 offen format:[BUF_DATA_FORMAT_32,BUF_NUM_FORMAT_FLOAT]
    # End program
    s_endpgm
```

This is a simple vector addition kernel, takes 3 arguments. `src1`, `src2` and `dst`.

Comment: Hello Nathan Lilienthal, excuse me, does Multi2Sim  support write-through cache? Thank you.@Nathan Lilienthal